# Python- selenium no responde elementos del html del portal de mi IP

Tags: python, selenium

tengo este fragmento de código donde intento automatizar el ingreso a una pagina desde el explorador, e imprimir todas las etiquetas `href` del cOdigo `html` de la misma. Hice prueba con una pagina "x" `(https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)` y me devuelve lo que debe, pero al hacerlo con una dirección `ip` `(http://192.168.10.214)`, solo abre la `ip` en el explorador pero no me devuelve las etiquetas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

respuesta de la pagina "x".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

respuesta del portal de la IP... alguna sugerencia ??

```
from selenium import webdriver   
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options= Options()

options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), 
            options=options)
driver.get("http://192.168.10.214")

links = driver.find_elements("xpath","//a[@href]")

for link in links:

    print(link.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Comment: 1. Para darle buen formato a tu código, pon acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del mismo. 2. Sabemos que tienes un problema, pero sé descriptivo/a en el título mismo. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, lee [ask] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.